# Jquery Validation and Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I'm trying to get an error message to show when my fields are missing input. Once both are filled in I want a success message to show in place of #error.
Not sure why I'm not getting any message currently.

```js
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      username: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      username: "please enter a name"
    }
  });
  alert("Submitted");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="pw">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
  </p>

  <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect -->
  <p id="error"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {

    if($("#username").val()==""){
        $("#error").html("Please enter a name");
        return;
    }
    if($("#pw").val()==""){
        $("#error").html("Password required");
        return;
    }
    alert("Submitted");
});
```

Comment: That totally worked! If I want to add the success message would it be an else after the ifs?

Comment: nope.. instead of «alert("Submitted");» : «$("#error").html("Submitted!");»

Comment: NOTE... That I totally skipped what could be defined has field validation ( elem.validate() ) that you didn't show the script. This just checks for empty fields.

Comment: Thanks again ! That works like a charm! I had done this in pure JS but needed to be modified to jQuery for full credit. Total noob with javascript, any tutorials or resources you'd recommend to a beginner?

Comment: Yeah just empty fields for now is fine

Comment: Look for W3C tutorials about jQuery... They are'nt always as complete as we would wish... But for the Basics it's ok.